# Photoshop px size is different from CSS px size

Tags: html, css

I have a mockup in photoshop which has a font at 60px. I set the font in the browser to be the same, at the same size of 60px, but in the browser the font is smaller. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: What resolution is the Photoshop file?

Comment: on photoshop 60 would be pt not px...

Comment: @SaurabhLP Photoshop can be configured to use px for its units rather than pt.

Comment: i am not sure that can be done...

Comment: @SaurabhLP it definitely can be...

Comment: not at all i am using photoshop cs4... for cs5 or cs6 i dnt know abt that... check the answer below..

Comment: @SaurabhLP It has been possible to do so since at least Photoshop 5 or 6:  Edit > Preferences > Units & Rulers.

Comment: I'm definitely using px, not pt.

Answer (score 1):

You have anti-aliasing on for your text in Photoshop?  Most browsers don't have that.

There is quite a bit of difference between how Photoshop renders text compared to how browsers render it (every browser has their own rendering engine, which might even vary depending on the OS).  It is impossible to replicate a Photoshop mockup pixel for pixel in a browser when there's text involved.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this tool, i am sure that would help you...

http://www.endmemo.com/sconvert/pixelpoint.php

From this it states that:- ***1px = 0.75pt***

Comment: Alright, doing tells me it should be 45pt. But that's not the same size as the text in photoshop either.